# Regex pattern to match special characters !@#$%^&* for a validatorJS rule

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex pattern I can use to check if a string contains any of the following characters with no other criteria: !@#$%^&*

Examples of passing strings are: '$', '4^', 'asdf&', '@asdf', '#$%'.

Any purely alphanumeric string would fail.

I am using this with validatorJS (https://github.com/skaterdav85/validatorjs) to be supplied as a regex rule.

Here is an example of using regex rules from the validatorJS docs:

```
var validation = new Validator({
    name: 'Doe',
    salary: '10,000.00',
    yearOfBirth: '1980'
}, {
    name: 'required|size:3',
    salary: ['required', 'regex:/^(?!0\\.00)\\d{1,3}(,\\d{3})*(\\.\\d\\d)?$/'],
    yearOfBirth: ['required', 'regex:/^(19|20)[\\d]{2,2}$/']
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a character class:

```
^.*[!@#$%^&*].*$
```